# ChartJS Dotted Line after 10 data points

Tags: chart.js

Currently, I have a graph, and I want it so that after 3 data points, the graph is a dotted line. (Attempting to do show current data + predictions on this graph)

Current Code

```
<canvas id="commands"></canvas>
    
    <script>
      var ctx = document.getElementById("commands");
      var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: ["03/14","03/16","Today","Tommorow"],
          datasets: [{
            data: ["0","0","23","90"],
          }],
        },
      });
    </script>
```

I'd like it  so that the line between 23-90 and any points after that is a dotted line, (this can be done for the whole graph by adding `borderDash: [10,5]`, but I'd like it to work for only certain points.)

Update: I've found a fiddle which does this, https://jsfiddle.net/uwb8357r/, but as you can see the tooltips look really bad.

Comment: have you tried splitting the data into two different series, and then making one solid and one dashed?

Comment: Won't the data overlap thou?

Comment: Update: I've found a fiddle which does this, https://jsfiddle.net/uwb8357r/, but as you can see the tooltips look really bad.

Comment: you'd have to declare x values for each point as well as y, but then they wouldn't overlap

Comment: The tooltips would...right?

https://file.coffee/u/f3OdezQw4.png
https://file.coffee/u/V9HRqpm65.png